# Checkout progress is not working anymore

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.0

I don't know what I did wrong, but currently my progess block at the onepage checkout is not working anymore, but for a few days it works really great.

I found some solutions and have tried some fixes for this problem, but nothing works for me :(.

My checkout.xml looks as follows:

```
<reference name="right">
  <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
  <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.progress.wrapper" translate="label">
    <label>Checkout Progress Wrapper</label>
    <action method="setElementId"><value>checkout-progress-wrapper</value></action>
    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
      <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
      <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
      <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
      <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
    </block>
  </block>
</reference>
```

I think it looks ok and I didn't changed it in the past. Currently I am using a custom theme and how I said, for a few days it was working without problems.

My last update was the customization of customtheme/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml which I copied from base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml and now looks as follows:

```
<?php $methods = $this->getMethods(); ?>
<?php $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1; ?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
  <dt><?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods'); ?></dt>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php foreach ($methods as $_method): ?>
    <?php $_code = $_method->getCode(); ?>
    <?php if ( ( $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod() == 'payonpickup_payonpickup' && ($_code == 'bankpayment' || $_code == 'paypal_express' || $_code == 'payonpickup') ) || $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod() == 'freeshipping_freeshipping' ):?>
        <dt>
        <?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
        <?php else: ?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method); ?>
        </label>
    </dt>
    <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
    <dd><?php echo $html; ?></dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('additional'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>
  payment.init();
  <?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
  payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
  <?php endif; ?>
  //]]>
</script>
```

But I don't know, if this file caused the problem, because when I undo this changes (delete methods.phtml), the progress block is still not working.

I hope you can help me, because I dispair :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error source was the "aromicon google universal analytics" extension, don't know why but if I deactivate this extension the checkout progress is working again :).

Answer (score 3):

I have revised code of this extension. I have saw that this extension rewrites `\magento\skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js` function. After comparing with prev version I noticed that method gotoSection has two params but not one like before. In short, just change in file `\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\aromicon\gua\gua.phtml:`

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section){
                var sectionElement = $('opc-'+section);
                sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
                this.accordion.openSection('opc-'+section);
                this.reloadProgressBlock(section);
                /**aromicon gua code*/
                try{ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': '<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>/'+section,'title': section});}catch(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
        };
```

to

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section, reloadProgressBlock){

            if (reloadProgressBlock) {
                this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
            }
            this.currentStep = section;
            var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
            sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
            this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
            if(!reloadProgressBlock) {
                this.resetPreviousSteps();
            }
                /**aromicon gua code*/
                try{ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': '<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>/'+section,'title': section});}catch(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
        };
```

For me it's work fine. Hopefully someone it will be useful.