# Onepage checkout progress not working anymore

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, javascript, upgrade

I've recently (yesterday) upgraded from magento **v1.7.7** to **1.9.2.2** . The problem is now that my onepage checkout **progress doesn't work anymore**. The 4 steps are shown but not the progress of them.

When I'm going the steps he shows in my Network:

[image]

But normally he should show something like this:

[image]

As you can see there's a difference with **prevStep** and **toStep**. Also the **progress** response isn't empty in the second case ... .

What could be the problem of this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the current Magento theme is not fully compatible with the upgraded version of Magento. There are 2 things that needs to be taken care of:

1) New set of handles for the checkout progress section. you will need to add it to the `checkout.xml` file(`layout\checkout.xml`). This is for the ajax responses.

```
<!-- Individual blocks for Progress steps begins -->
<checkout_onepage_progress_billing>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml">
        <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_progress_billing>


<checkout_onepage_progress_shipping>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml">
        <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_progress_shipping>


<checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml">
        <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>

<checkout_onepage_progress_payment>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_info" name="payment_info">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
        <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_progress_payment>

<!-- end individual progress blocks -->
```

2) Add the new element ids in the `progress.phtml` file(`template\checkout\onepage\progress.phtml`) so that the ajax request results will be updated to the elements. The new version has added these ids and my older theme didn't had these ids. Check this [diff](http://www.mergely.com/GgaOKoMb/).

Just in case the diff expired in future: [image]

The screenshot show only 2 instances and there are 4 similar instances that needs update.

In this particular case step #1 seems to be taken care of

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. This is the correct answer, I don't know why isn't accepted. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you install **Aromicon Google Universal Analytics** module?

If so, then it's this module which is breaking the onestep checkout progress. Following are the solutions:

**Solution #1:** Follow the link below
[Checkout progress is not working anymore](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41798/checkout-progress-is-not-working-anymore)

**Solution #2:** Delete the **Aromicon Google Universal Analytics** module & use either Magento built-in analytics or copy the code manually or look for another module.

Solution #1 fixed the onestep checkout progress for me.